# add hyperlink to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a webpage using C# and asp.net
I have a simple sqlite database.
I have a gridview where i am displaying just simple 2 Book categories.
The two categories are
Fiction
technical

I would like to assign a link to those categories so the user can be directed to a new page.

Here is a snapshot of the data being displayed in the gridview..
where i want to add a link to Fiction and technical to redirect to  a new page.
[image]
This is my dataset and gridview.

```
 DataSet dsgrid;
 dsgrid = (DataSet)Cache["GridViewDataSet"];
 if (dsgrid == null)
 {
 dsgrid = GetDataSet();  //call function
 Cache["GridViewDataSet"] = dsgrid;

 }
 else
 {

 }
 //bind our cache data to a datasource
 GridView1.DataSource = dsgrid.Tables[0];
 GridView1.DataBind();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 this.lblError.Text = ex.Message;
 }

 }

 private DataSet GetDataSet()
 {

        String connectionString = "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\bookDB.db");
        String selectCommand = "Select * from Category";
        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

        //GridView1.DataSource = ds;
       // GridView1.DataBind();

        return ds;

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You should do this in ASPX/ASCX UI layout by adding HyperLInc control in the GridView template. Show ASPX/ASCX code for gridView

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options, which one you choose will depend on the amount of flexibility you need.

**Built in button column:**

```
    <asp:GridView >
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonColumn DataField="some_field" Visible="false" ButtonType="linkButton" />         
        </Columns>
    /<asp:GridView >
```

**Column template:**  (This will give you the most flexibility.)

```
<asp:GridView>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Its a link!">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="SomeName" runat="server" Text=''>
            </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: your examples are good but i want to add the link to the existing categorynames( fiction, technical) that are being pulled from a database.

Answer (score 1):

this is the markup code, you have to add a hyperlink to the gridview control inside the IntemTempalte  collection and add a binding expression to the text property of the contained controls

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="128px">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCodigo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("columnNae")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("columnNae") %>' NavigateUrl="http://nudierweb.somee.com"></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. However, i want to make it navigate to two different websites is that possible?

Comment: Can i add the link to yahoo.com on the category FICTION and microsoft.com to category TECHNICAL?.. As it stands the link is under the category and anything under that row has the same link. What i mean is i want two hyperlinks under the column items and not just under the column name.

Comment: you can add a column in your database containing the urls where the user is gonna be redirect and in the NavigateUrl attribute of the HyperLink control use a binding expression like this.      <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("columnNae") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("UrlColumn") %>'></asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HyperLinc control

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="http://www.yournavigateurl.com"
              Text="Your Hyperlink text" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but in context you need to add a bit more for this to be useful - how might you add a hyperlink control (I can think of a couple of ways) how might you bind it to the data so that the name and the link are dependent on the source, etc, etc.

Comment: I get an error: 
            Error Creating Control - GridView1System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'asp:HyperLink' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'.

Comment: what is the using command to bind to hyperlink? I dont seem to have it

Comment: the answer below points you to the right direction on how to do it, you need to add Hyperlink control to your data grid and evaluate it's text value from database. <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("columnNae") %>' NavigateUrl="http://nudierweb.somee.com"></asp:HyperLink>
System.Web.UI.WebControls should be ok for the using command

Comment: I got it to work using Nudier example thank you. However, i need it to navigate to two different pages.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

`<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Value of column you want to make as HYPERLINK" HeaderText="COLUMN NAME" runat="server" DataNavigateUrlFields="Value you want to pass to other page(fname)" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/demo.aspx(another page name)?fname**strong text**={0}"/>`

eg:

`<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="stid" HeaderText="stid" Target="_self" runat="server" DataNavigateUrlFields="fname" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/demo.aspx?fname={0}"/>`

Comment: What does this code do? How does it address the problem?