# Adding multiple parameter in querystring

Tags: querystringparameter

I would like to know how to add another parameter to this querystring.

```
e.Item.Cells[0].Text = "<a  title=\"Click to see " + 
functions.email.getFullName(e.Item.Cells[0].Text) + 
"'s Pending Requests\" href=\"default.aspx?U=" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text + 
"\">" + functions.email.getFullName(e.Item.Cells[0].Text) + "</a>";
```

Comment: e.Item.Cells[0].Text = "<a  title=\"Click to see " + functions.email.getFullName(e.Item.Cells[0].Text) + "'s Pending Requests\" href=\"default.aspx?U=" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text + "\">" + functions.email.getFullName(e.Item.Cells[0].Text) + "</a>";

Comment: Sorry the above one is the statement which i am trying to pass parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid your question seems a bit unclear.  To me, it looks like you are setting the value of `e.Item.Cells[0].Text=` to a string.  Isn't that string itself a parameter?  If it is, did you mean that you are wanting to *concatenate* another value to it?

It would also be helpful to to include the function in which you are setting this as well, for more context.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am adding a hyperlink to a column of a gridview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274749/add-hyperlink-to-a-gridview - Such as in this example?

Comment: 'HyperLink hyperLinkCtrl = new HyperLink();
hyperLinkCtrl.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;      hyperLinkCtrl.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com"; e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(hyperLinkCtrl)'